# How to get a reference to a custom UITableView header created with .xib file?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My table view has a separate .xib files for both: cells and headers. Both are subclasses of UITableViewCell. I set up the header by calling `viewForHeaderInSection` UITableViewDelegate's delegate method and everything worked perfectly until I had to add a button to the said header.

I want to update the button's image after each tap but to do that I need a reference to the header where the button is located. I know that it's possible to get a reference to the header by calling `myTableView.headerView(forSection:)` but that method returns an instance of  `UITableViewHeaderFooterView?`- because of that I'm unable to access the header's button since cast from 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView?' to my custom subclass of `UITableViewCell` always fails.

How can I get a reference to the header where the button was tapped?

---

Edit:

In the end I went with @shivi_shub answer but instead of adding a target to the header's button I used closures:

1. In my custom header class (subclass of UITableViewCell) I created an action and an outlet for the button. I also added an additional variable `var expandCompletionHandler: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)? = nil`. In the button's action I passed self to the created closure ( expandCompletionHandler(self) )
2. In my ViewController class (where the table view is located) in the `viewForHeaderInSection` right after setting up the the header view I assigned a closure to the previously created variable like that:

   header.expandCompletionHandler = { header in
                   if header.expandBtn.tag == section {
                       // Change buttons image here
                   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add Target to your header button in viewForHeaderInSection method -

```
header.button.tag = section
header.button.addTarget(self, action:
            #selector(YourViewController.btnClicked(_:)),
                                   for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

@objc func btnClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //check button tag here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the HeaderFooterView to you custom class.

```
let headerView = myTableView.headerView(forSection:)
if let = headerView as? MyHeaderViewClass {
    headerView.myProperty = someValue
}
```

Comment: It was my first thought to do just that but since my header's class is a subclass of UITableViewCell I get a warning that
"Cast from 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView' to unrelated type 'ExpandableTableViewHeader' (my header's class) always fails"

Comment: Okay..but the ideal scenario would be to use UITableViewHeaderFooterView itself.

Comment: I tried but Xcode wouldn't allow me to create a .xib file with a subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView. After reading a few questions about custom table view headers (using xibs), a lot of people suggest to subclass UITableViewCell. 
I assumed it was common practice to create custom header this way.